# Shall I use continuous tense for both action in this sentence?

Tags: continuous

Is it correct to write:

> I hope, my name, when you are reading it, **will ring** a bell.

Or should I write:

> I hope my name, when you are reading it **will be  ringing** a bell.

Is it correct to use continuous tense for both the actions? I think the first one is better but don't know why. (may be because it is the first action)

Comment: You don't need the continuous tense for either. Reading a name is not a continuing action

Comment: i thought that continuous could express the future it is not now but in the future. it is a not an habit but a specific action

Comment: The continuous can express the future in sentences like "I'm going to the seaside for my holidays", but not in this context.

Comment: Why is in this context not possible to use it

Comment: You could use it if you were talking about the other person reading a book (for example), but it only takes a moment for a literate person to read a name, so it sounds odd to use the continuous tense.

Comment: but I thought present simple was for habitual action

Comment: As a note, the most clear and simple way to write the sentence is "I hope my name will ring a bell when you read it." Splitting "my name" and "will ring" in this case by putting "when you read it" in the middle is a little clunky.

Comment: just would like to know if I can use when reading it (I on't think so) but would like to have the confirmation.

Comment: The present simple _can_ be used for a habitual action, but that isn't its only use!